# How to write a data into the application.properties file in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on some automation stuff, in which I just want to write the values into the application.properties file as shown below:

```
project.ids = 01234, 56789, 14587,...
```

So here, my key(`project.ids`) will be the same, I just want to append the `ids` to the previously stored values (shown above). Whenever my service will be called a new project id will be generated so I just want to append or store the value in the property file to the same key(`project.ids`).

Could anyone help or suggest here how can I achieve this?
Any suggestions around how to write the value to the `application.properties` file in Java?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use the `Environment` class of Spring. But it is only used to read properties and not write them.

what you could do is follow this way:

1. Load the `.properties` file:

```java
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
prop.load(in);
```

2. Get the value as it is of the property

```java
String ids = prop.getProperty("project.ids");
```

3. Set the new value

```java
String ids = prop.setProperty("project.ids", ids + ", 12324...");
```

PS: I wouldn't play around with the `.properties` file much, it is mostly used for configurations. Try saving your ids in a DB, Spring can be very helpful for that.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I don't want to lose any value. If I will use like this - String ids = prop.setProperty("project.ids", ids + ", 12324...");, then probably I will lose the values which is previously stored. I want to append the values without losing previous values.

Comment: That's exactly what `ids + ", new ids.."` does. The variable `ids` holds the old data that was stored. That's why we take the old data and append the new data to the end of it.

Comment: Correct but these variables(ids, newIds) will get flushed out whenever I will restart my server. I don't want that, that's why I am storing each id in property file every time whenever my service is getting called so that I can take those id without losing any  one and use it accordingly..

Comment: I do not understand... The values will not be flushed out. They will be written to the .properties file and stay there.

Comment: Okay, so you mean to say I will define 2 keys in properties file as newIds & oldIds and I will store & fetch the values accordingly. Is that correct?

Comment: No. You have only one property. It's like a `String` variable. And the value of this variable is saved in the `.properties` file. You get the value of this variable `project.ids` and then you add something at the end of this variable. You append its value. And then you write it back. For example: Project ids before the update: `project.ids=21341`. After: `project.ids=21341, iAmNew`